# Cannot execute Checked event when property change

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Combobox that bound a list of `Contact` defined in that way:

```
public List<Contact> Contacts { get;set; } = new List<Contact>();

public class Contact
{ 
    public bool IsFavourite { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

NB: the `Contact` class implement `INotifyPropertyChange`, that I don't wrote in the example.

The `Contacts` list is bounded on the `ComboBox` in the following way:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CombinedTemplate}" />
```

where `CombinedTemplate` contains the following:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="NormalItemTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding Name}" Checked="Contact_Checked" Unchecked="Contact_Unchecked" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="CombinedTemplate">
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Presenter" Content="{Binding}"
        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource NormalItemTemplate}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

as you can see I bounded the `IsChecked` of `CheckBox` to the `IsChecked` property that is valorized behind code, so suppose that in the `Contacts` list is added this item:

```
var contact = new Contact();
    contact.IsChecked = true;
    contact.IsFavourite = true;
    contact.Name = "Foo";
Contacts.Add(contact);
```

the `Checked` of the `CheckBox` should firing automatically 'cause the `IsChecked` is true, but I doesn't get this working.

What I did wrong? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

As suggested in the answer for fix this "bug" I should handle the `Loaded` event, so I did:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}"
      Loaded="ContactMenuComboBox_Loaded"
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CombinedTemplate}" />
```

in the event I did:

```
private void ContactMenuComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var contact in Contacts)
    {
        if (contact.IsFavourite)
        {
            contact.IsChecked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

the `IsChecked` property is setted correctly, unfortunately the `IsChecked` event isn't firing.

Forget to say, if I put the code of `ContactMenuComboBox_Loaded` inside a button, and then press it, well the event `IsChecked` will firing.

This is a really weird situation.

**UPDATE #2**

This is the content of `Checked` event:

```
private void Contact_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var contact = (sender as CheckBox).DataContext as CheckedListItem<Model.Contact>;

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        ContactController.GetLeagues(contact);
    })
    .ContinueWith((prevTask) =>
    {
        CheckTaskException(prevTask);
    });
}
```

Comment: have you tried applying Mode=TwoWay in your binding??

Comment: use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List` in the `Contacts` property

Comment: @VishalPrajapati In case you mean the IsChecked Binding, note that this property binds TwoWay by default.

Comment: @VishalPrajapati yes I also tried that.

Comment: another wrong point needs to be corrected (I saw it now)
`List<Contacts> Contacts`   --> `List<Contact> Contacts`

Comment: @CelsoLívero fix typo in the question

Comment: Why are you handling the Checked event at all?

Comment: @mm8 I need to execute a method when the check event, or in this case, when the `IsFavourite` variable is true. Actually if I valorize the list with specific elements with `IsFavourite = True` the method is never firing

Comment: So why don't you call this method in the setter of the IsChecked property?

Comment: @mm8 I can't the setter is defined in a dll which contains all the models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

I have checked with WPF and you are indeed right! The **first** binding **evaluation does not fire** the `Checked` event, only the subsequent calls do. This is in contrast to UWP, where the event is fired.

As a workaround, you could handle the `Loaded` event if you need to perform an action right after the value is first bound. However, if you are implementing the app as MVVM, you might be better off pushing the `Checked` logic in the setter of the `IsChecked` property.

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" 
             Content="{Binding Name}" 
             Loaded="Contact_Loaded"
             Checked="Contact_Checked" Unchecked="Contact_Unchecked" />
```

And in the `Loaded` method do something like:

```
var checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;
if ( checkbox.IsChecked ) Contact_Checked(this, e);
if ( !checkbox.IsChecked ) Contact_UnChecked(this, e);
```

### Update 2

If you just want to execute the actions as soon as possible, you can indeed attach the `Loaded` event to your window and do the following:

```
foreach (var contact in Contacts)
{
    if (contact.IsFavourite)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
           ContactController.GetLeagues(contact);
        })
        .ContinueWith((prevTask) =>
        {
           CheckTaskException(prevTask);
        });
    }
}
```

Of course to avoid code duplication, you could extract this code into a separate method with a `Contact` parameter.

### Original answer

The problem is that your `Contacts` property is a normal `List`. In this case the data-bound controls will not update with any changes to that list after first binding. You should use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead:

```
public ObservableCollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; } =
    new ObservableCollection<Contact>();
```

In addition I don't see a point of having two data templates when one of them contains just a `ContentPresenter` for the other. You could simplify it into just `NormalItemTemplate`:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NormalItemTemplate}" />
```

Finally, the data-binding for `Name` is not correct, the `Item.` prefix should not be there:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="NormalItemTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" 
             Content="{Binding Name}" 
             Checked="Contact_Checked" Unchecked="Contact_Unchecked" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I already though this but it's not the problem. I tried already with an `ObservableCollection`

Comment: change to a full property autoproperty will not notify property change

Comment: So I guess it's a bug of WPF?

Comment: It is not a bug per-se. It depends on the perspective. You might look at it in the way that the checkbox is getting checked, so the event should be triggered, but also in the way that it is created already "pre-checked" so there is not a reason to fire the event :-D . Anyway, you may handle the `Loaded` event if you want to perform an action right after it loads with the first bound value

Comment: What have you changed?

Comment: The reason it is not firing is that the checkbox is already checked because of the binding. You are essentially setting `contact.IsChecked` to the same value it already has, so the event does not fire. I originally meant a different thing with the `Loaded` event, pleas see my answer, I have updated the first part with an example

Comment: @MartinZikmund oh yeah, your logic sounds good now. The only problem for me is that: when I cast the sender as `CheckBox` I get null, maybe 'cause the `CheckBox` is available in the `DataTemplate` of the `ComboBox`? The sender infact is a `ComboBox`

Comment: No, you should add the `Loaded` event to the checkbox, not to the combobox :-) ( `<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" 
             Content="{Binding Name}" 
             Loaded="Contact_Loaded" ...` )

Comment: @MartinZikmund mm thanks, but I'm not able to get the `Checked` event firing, maybe 'cause the items are inside a `<VirtualizingStackPanel MinWidth="250"/>`? The strange thing is that the `Checked` event si firing only when I click on the `ComboBox`, when instead I was added the `Loaded` event on the `ComboBox` this not happened. What do you think?

Comment: What do you actually want to do inside the `Checked` event? It is firing only after you click the `ComboBox`, because that is when the `CheckBox` is actually created (it does not exist until that moment) and its `Loaded` event executes

Comment: We are basically using the `Loaded` event handler to "force call" the `Checked` or `Unchecked` event

Comment: @MartinZikmund When the `Checked` event is called, I need to load all the information of the favourite contact inside a `DataGrid`. I don't know if you have time to open a chat, unfortunately I've no enough rep

Comment: Could you post the code of the `Checked` event as well?

Comment: @MartinZikmund sure, I updated the question with the content of `Checked` event

Comment: I have added new update to my answer, you can add this to `ComboBox` or `Window` loaded handler

Comment: @MartinZikmund Thanks for your time and your help, unfortunately I can't upvote your answer, I accepted it, thanks again! Have a great day!